# Creating a distribution File

Tags: python

Just starting out with Python, Flask, etc, and trying to create a distribution file, below is the code I have come up with and it says "syntax Error" I can't figure it out....

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
name= 'vsearch',
version= '1.0',
description= 'The Head First Python Search Tools',
author= 'HF Python 2e',
author_email= 'hfpy2e@gmail.com',
url= 'headfirstlabs.com', 
py_modules= ['vsearch'],
)
```

Error:

```
File "setup.py", line 10 py_modules=['vsearch'] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The code below "setup" is indented properly on my end, couldn't post it on this board without it setup like that

Comment: can you post the error that you're getting?

Comment: File "setup.py", line 10
    py_modules=['vsearch'],
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is because of identation

```
setup(
    name= "vsearch",
    version= "1.0",
    description= "The Head First Python Search Tools",
    author= "HF Python 2e",
    author_email= "hfpy2e@gmail.com",
    url= "headfirstlabs.com", 
    py_modules= ['vsearch'],
)
```

Comment: I believe I have the indent correct as when I hit the "enter" button it indents on each line, should I be manually indenting a certain number?

Comment: can you try copy pasting the the indented version and running it?

Comment: That worked!!! In the future should I be indenting manually? Thank you very much, as you can tell i'm quite green and created my profile here just to ask this question, appreciate your help with this.

Comment: np! Just remember that indentation is really important in python. You should use tabs to indent whenever required